# Cannot retrieve text box value in java script popup

Tags: php, javascript, html

I want to pass a text box value in parent.php to my popup window(child_page.php). Following is my code.
parent.php-

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">

var popupWindow=null;

function child_open()
{ 

popupWindow =window.open('child_page.php',"_blank","directories=no, status=no, menubar=no, scrollbars=yes, resizable=no,width=600, height=280,top=200,left=200");

}
function parent_disable() {
if(popupWindow && !popupWindow.closed)
popupWindow.focus();
}
</script>

 <input type="text" name="myTextField" id="myTextField" required="required"/>


</head>
<body onFocus="parent_disable();" onclick="parent_disable();">
    <a href="javascript:child_open()">Click me</a>
</body>    

</html>
```

child_page.php

```
<h1>child page</h1>


<script>
    window.onunload = refreshParent;
    function refreshParent() {
        window.opener.location.reload();
    }
    var x=parent.document.getElementById('myTextField').value

    <?php echo x; ?>
</script>

<?php 

//how do I get the textbox value here.

    ?>
```

I googled it and tried to do it. Since I know little about java script couldn't pull those answers together as a solution.

Comment: Why not first set the variable to a session?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many errors in your html. You are writing input element before closing head tag. Move it inside body. And try something like this:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">

    var popupWindow=null;

    function child_open(val){ 
        popupWindow =window.open('child_page.php' + "?val=" + val,"_blank","directories=no, status=no, menubar=no, scrollbars=yes, resizable=no,width=600, height=280,top=200,left=200");
    }

    function parent_disable() {
        if(popupWindow && !popupWindow.closed)
            popupWindow.focus();
    }
</script>

</head>
<body onFocus="parent_disable();" onclick="parent_disable();">
    <input type="text" name="myTextField" id="myTextField" required="required"/>
    <a href="#" onclick="var val = document.getElementById('myTextField').value; child_open(val);return false">Click me</a>
</body>    

</html>
```

Now in your `child_page.php` you can get the value using `$_GET['val']`.

```
//child_page.php

<h1>child page</h1>
<?php $x = $_GET['val']; ?>
<script>
    window.onunload = refreshParent;
    function refreshParent() {
        window.opener.location.reload();
    }   
</script>

<?php echo $x; ?>
```